# Visual Studio 2015 property pages error

Tags: visual-studio

When trying to change the platform toolset to v141 in vs2015 update3 community my property pages on the project is missing most of the info. This is what my property pages look like where it should look like the second

https://i.stack.imgur.com/7w704.jpg

https://msdnshared.blob.core.windows.net/media/2016/02/prop-pages-all-toolsets.png

Comment: Yes, that is what the setting pages look like for a Makefile project.  Nothing much to configure since it is all done by the makefile.  There is no problem here.

Comment: ok how do I change it from a makefile project? It's downloaded from a UE4 github project I uploaded a while back as a backup, my computer broke now I'm trying to restore the git backup but it won't compile because I need to be able to change the toolset.

Comment: Apparently it is still broken, it can't compile a project it used to be able to compile before.  When you don't take the time to properly document compile errors then you'll need a site where clairvoyants give free advice.

Comment: The compile error is simple. It wants toolset v141, but can only compile in vs 2015, hence why I need to get into the settings for the toolset.